# Snowflake error 000002 (0A000): Unsupported feature 'unsupported_requested_format:snowflake' while loading file into local storage using get command

Tags: get, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stage

Trying to get a file from  stage into my local storage via Snowflake GET command but command gets greyed out and gives the above  error.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY STAGE my_temp_stage;

COPY INTO @my_temp_stage/output_filex
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table_name)
FILE_FORMAT = ( 
 TYPE='CSV' 
 COMPRESSION=GZIP 
 FIELD_DELIMITER=',' 
 ESCAPE=NONE 
 ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD=NONE 
 date_format='AUTO' 
 time_format='AUTO' 
 timestamp_format='AUTO'
 binary_format='UTF-8' 
 field_optionally_enclosed_by='"' 
 null_if='' 
 EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE 
)  
overwrite=TRUE 
single=FALSE 
max_file_size=5368709120 
header=TRUE;
```

I'm using the below GET command to load above file into my local

```
GET @my_temp_stage/my_temp_stage/output_filex_0_0_0.csv.gz file://C:\Users\zn\Downloads;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the command in the Web UI? It is only supported from a driver/connector such as SnowSQL

Comment: I am running it on Snowsight WebUI

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running the command in Snowflake worksheet. You can get your files from the internal stage using SnowSQL client.

1. Download the client: https://developers.snowflake.com/snowsql/
2. Install it on your PC
3. Connect to Snowflake using SnowSQL:

3.1. Open a command prompt or terminal window.

3.2. Type `snowsql -a <account_identifier> -u <username>` and hit enter to start the SnowSQL application. See this [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier) how to get the account identifier.

3.3. Enter your Snowflake password when prompted

3.4. Run commands: `use database <db_name>` and `use schema <schema_name>` to select the db and schema where your internal stage is created

4. then you can run your command:

```
GET @my_temp_stage/my_temp_stage/output_filex_0_0_0.csv.gz file://C:\Users\zn\Downloads;
```